# Take integer value from database and cast it to Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I'm all new to `Enum` types and seems like I can't figure something out in my project. I was asked to use `Enum` for creating a combobox with pre-defined values. What I did was:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class LastStatus
    {
        public LastStatus()
        {
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public enum description { inProgress, done, accepted }

        public description desc;
        public int constant { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And this is my method for converting the DB model to my own model before I use them: (e.g add them to a List and then iterate over it to add to the combobox's listitems in aspx.cs side)

```
private Models.LastStatus ConvertStatusDbToObject(DBModel.myDB.LastStatu status)
        {
            Models.LastStatus statusObject = new Models.LastStatus();
            statusObject.ID = status.ID;
            //statusObject.description = status.description;
            (LastStatus.description)statusObject.desc = (LastStatus.description)status.@const;
            statusObject.constant = status.@const;

            return statusObject;
        }
```

I get the error on this line:

```
(LastStatus.description)statusObject.desc = (LastStatus.description)status.@const;
```

when trying to cast the integer value of the DB Model to my enum type. Isn't `desc` a property?

> Error 23  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable,
>   property or indexer

Comment: `object o = new object(); o = (int)1;` is OK but this is not `object o = new object(); (int)o = (int)1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `(LastStatus.description)statusObject.desc = (LastStatus.description)status.@const;` to `statusObject.desc = (LastStatus.description)status.@const;`

You don't need to cast the property itself!

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't realize that. I guess I'm tired after all during this internship :D Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

**First**, assign integer values to your enum values when declaring the enum. for example:

```
public enum description { inProgress = 0, done = 1, accepted = 2}
```

**Second**, I would recommend against having public fields in your class. change

```
public description desc;
```

to

```
public description desc { get; set; };
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. enums start from 0 by default,no?

Comment: Actually yes, I forgot about that. However the second recommendation is still valid. Check out Sweeper's answer, I think he got it right :-)

Comment: Yeah, will accept as an answer as soon as Stackoverflow lets me :)

Comment: What do you mean "as soon as Stackoverflow lets me "? You can always do that, can't you?

Comment: Well there is a cooldown before you get to accept an answer. Thanks for the fast reply again!